# Is there any best tutorials for the building application with rails and extjs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, extjs4

I have worked on Ext js and Ruby on rails but not together. I just want to learn the tutorial for building web application with Extjs and the back end should be Rails.

Thanks in advance.

-Raghavendra

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Extjs 4 & Rails(3+4). The work is really the same, just add the files and use extjs normally with AJAX.

Extjs and Rails both works on MVC system, so make sure they have the same properties in the model, use `type: 'rest'` in the store, and use less the view rendering.

there are also some gems you can find like `extjs-rails`, I perfer just embed the files.

here is a tutorial from 2009: http://wwww.extjs.com/blog/ext-js-on-rails-a-comprehensive-tutorial/